# Zebra CPCL printer issue with non-english unicode characters

Tags: windows-mobile, zebra-printers, zpl

I am trying to print some labels using the Citizen   printer in .NET enviroment. In order to do that i use a P30CPCl.dll which is provided by the manufacturer along with a relevant manual which is pretty much identical to the one found here : ftp://ftp.maxatec-europe.com/Maxatec/LK-P/LK-P41/Driver/Mobile%20Driver/English/Manuals/LK-P41(CPCL)%20Program%20Manual_English.pdf , since apparently many or all CPCL printers use the same .dll.

I have no problem printing english characters, but when it comes to greek characters i get "????? ???" instead. The function's signature does not seem to support a codepage :

> public static extern Int32 CPCLPrintText(Int32 Rotation, Int32
>   FontType, Int32 FontSize, string PrintX, string PrintY, string Data,
>   Int32 count);

Any ideas what I can do to print  non-latin characters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted Citizen customer support and they told me that "CMP-30 supports ASCII code table up to 7f, so Greek characters will not be supported in CPCL mode." So the only way to do it is via ESC/POS.. tough luck

Answer (score 0):

Possible root causes:

- the printer does not support unicode printing
  (the Zebra CPCL programmers manual states only Latin-1, Latin-9 and 
  CP850 support)
- the font does not have the glyph for the unicode char
- print a font sample page (if printer supports such test page)
- the DLL does not support unicode

Does Citizen provide a programmers manual for the printer?
Does Citizen provide a reference manual for the printer?
Do you need to use this DLL or can you code directly?
Does the printer also support different printer language?
Which printer model is this exactly?

EDIT1:
according to the citizen manual the printer does not support a greek containing code page:

```
N. COUNTRY/CODE PAGE Command
The COUNTRY control command substitutes the appropriate character set for the specified country,
Format
{command} {name}
Command & option
{command} COUNTRY
{name} USA
GERMANY
FRANCE
SWEDEN
SPAIN
NORWAY
CHINA (double byte encoding)
ITALY
CP850
UK
BIG5 (Traditional Chinese; double byte encoding)
JAPAN-S (Simplified Japanese fonts; double byte encoding)
```

Comment: The printer model is Citizen CMP-30, it is indeed advertisted as supporting different printer language (http://www.racoindustries.com/citizen-cmp-30-printer-features.htm). Citizen does provide a "program manual" which is pretty much identical to the one i posted in the original post. I guess there is a way to code directly but it would be a lot more work and something that would have to be the very last option. (this is the low level command manual : https://www.citizen-systems.co.jp/support/download/printer/cmp20_30data/E/CMP-30CPCL-CMD002E.pdf)